# "[Errno 2]. No such file or directory: b'apt-get'", "rc": 2

Tags: apt, python3, amazon-ec2, ansible

I don't know why when I run my ansible-playbook to install packages on ec2-instances using apt-get this appears.`[WARNING]: Updating cache and auto-installing missing dependency: python3-apt fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "apt-get update", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'apt-get'", "rc": 2}`.

Here is what my ansible code does to install packages on ubuntu.

```
 - name: Install packages for jenkins-docker-worker
hosts:
  - localhost
gather_facts: no

tasks:
  - name: Install docker
    apt:
      name: docker
      state: latest

  - name: start docker
    service:
        name: docker
        state: started

  - name: Ensure group "docker" exists
    group:
      name: docker
      state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not targeting an Amazon Linux 2 instance, since it uses `yum` as a package manager, instead of `apt`.